# Can change select clause when input is null?

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I want to do a select in a table named ALBARANES that it's going to show me all 
the columns of the table. This select has inputs values to do the where clauses.

**Inputs:** @serie, @client

What I want is: If @serie's value is null then show me all the columns regardles of the column value of ALBARANES.SERIE, but if @serie has a value not null then do a clause using it.

```
SELECT * FROM ALBARANES AC 
WHERE 
AC.SERIE = @serie/*Code when @serie has value not null*/
AC.FECHA < (SELECT CAST ('Now' as date) from RDB$DATABASE)
```

And the same with the input @client. **How can I implement this select?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
WHERE (AC.SERIE = @serie or @serie is null) and
      ac.fecha < date(now())
```

Your question is tagged MySQL.  However, your date logic is not MySQL, so I changed it.  If your question is mistagged, then you may want your original logic.

Comment: That help me a lot. Thanks! And sorry for the tag error.